# Modifying torrc for openvpn?

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

When using a VPN, should I make any changes to my torrc? Such as defining the default route on (tun0) 10.4.0.1?

Using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: You might set `OutboundBindAddress`, I guess.

Comment: I guess? I take it that means no modifications to torrc are needed for making openvpn work more elegantly with tor?

Comment: Tor has no concept of interfaces, if your VPN is setup correctly to route internet bound traffic then Tor will use it.